# Developing an Android App - The best system

Tags: java, android, cordova, titanium

I'm in the process of starting an android app - however i'm confused as to what is the best option to take with regards to the development of an android app.

What would be the best system to use? Phonegap, Titanium, Feedhenry or a native android app using java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/172496)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what kind of App it is.

If you are not going to need any significant interaction with web API's or it is not a kind of web-android-app -> you should go with native android.

Else if you need to use some web-service which requires you to access it from a browser then you should consider using Phonegap, Titanium etc.....

What Phonegap, Titanium etc.. do is -> they deploy a special Activity which Extends Android Activity class to start a highly customized Android Web View + they provide a javascript interface for most Android functionality. So you can just make an HTML page and handle all your application logic using javascript.

My experience with phonegap etc -> if you have more complicated application logic -> you will end up with a messy javascript code.